# File path issue with Meson and Eigen

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen, meson-build

I cannot make local include paths work in the Meson build system.

This C++ inclusion works correctly:

```
#include </cygdrive/c/Users/user/project/Third-Party/eigen/Eigen/Dense>
```

This one does not:

```
#include "Third-Party/eigen/Eigen/Dense"
```

> fatal error: Eigen/Dense: No such file or directory

In the Meson build file, I tried to add Eigen's path, without success:

```
# '.' will refer to current build directory
include_dirs = include_directories('include', '.', '../project/Third-Party/eigen')
```

This is the project tree structure:

```
project
   meson.build
   src
      meson.build
      example.h
      example.cpp
   Third-Party
      eigen  (headers only lib)
         Eigen
```

Note: with CMake I do not have this issue.

Comment: Does adding `/cygdrive/c/Users/user/project/Third-Party/eigen/` to `include_directories` work? (And writing `#include <Eigen/Dense>` in the c++ file). Writing absolute paths in c++ files is not a good idea.

Comment: @chtz: now I get an error directly from Meson, and not the compiler: "meson.build:28:0: ERROR:  Tried to form an absolute path to a source dir. You should not do that but use relative paths instead."

Comment: And the `'../project/Third-Party/eigen'` together with `#include <Eigen/Dense>` does not work, either?

Comment: No: that was my first attempt.

Answer (score 4):

For dependency management, meson allows you to manually declare [`include_directories()`](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#include_directories) in your build files. However, there is another way do handle dependencies: using [`dependency()`](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#dependency) command.

`dependency()` is a much better way to handle dependencies, because meson will build it if necessary (if dependency is a shared or a static library) and *safely* allows you to use includes. That means that you don't have to know where includes for dependency are located physically or care about their paths ever after. The only downside is that this kind of dependency needs it's own `meson.build` file.

### Using `dependency()` command:

To actually use it, you have to [write a wrap file](http://mesonbuild.com/Wrap-dependency-system-manual.html) for dependency. Or, if you are lucky enough, there is already a wrap file for you in the [Wrap DB](https://wrapdb.mesonbuild.com/) -- a community-driven database for meson wrap files. Wrap file is a config of some kind that declare where you can get a dependency and in what form. Wrap file can wrap around zip archives and git repositories.

For your given dependency, there is wrap file in Wrap DB: [eigen](https://wrapdb.mesonbuild.com/eigen). All you have to do is download it and place it in the `subprojects` directory near your `meson.build`. For example:

```
$ cd project
$ mkdir subprojects
$ wget "https://wrapdb.mesonbuild.com/v1/projects/eigen/3.3.4/1/get_wrap" \
  -O subprojects/eigen.wrap
```

Now, not every project builds with meson. For the ones that don't, wrap file also specify a *patch*. Patch is used to just copy appropriate `meson.build` file into dependency directory (as well as any other files that would be needed for building that particular dependency with meson). Eigen wrap file contains a patch.

To find out how any particular dependency *declare* itself as a dependency (using [`declare_dependency()`](http://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#declare_dependency) command), you need to investigate `meson.build` file in dependency source directory (although it's often just *name of the dependency* plus *_dep*, e.g. "eigen_dep"). For me, *eigen* directory was `subprojects/eigen-eigen-5a0156e40feb`. So, you search for the `declare_dependency()` command:

```
$ grep declare_dependency subprojects/eigen-eigen-5a0156e40feb/meson.build
eigen_dep = declare_dependency(
```

As you can see, eigen declare dependency as `eigen_dep`. If you want to know what *exactly* is declared, just scroll down the dependency `meson.build` file.

Now, to use that `eigen_dep` in your project, create a dependency object with a `dependency()` command. Here is a sample project that I used to compile "A simple first program" from [Eigen: Getting Started](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html):

```
project('example', 'cpp')
eigen_dependency = dependency('eigen', fallback: ['eigen', 'eigen_dep'])
executable('example', 'example.cpp', dependencies: eigen_dependency)
```

Notice arguments for the `dependency()` command. The first one is system-wide dependency that meson is searching for. If there is no *eigen* for development installed in your system, then meson uses *fallback*: first item in fallback is basename of the wrap file, second item is a name of declared dependency.

Then use `eigen_dependency` variable in whatever you build, passing it to the *dependencies* argument.

### Using `include_directories()` command:

If you want to just include some files from external directory (such as your "Third-Party" directory) using `include_directories()` command, that directory has to be relative to the `meson.build` file where you use it.

To use manually declared includes, you need to call `include_directories()` command to get the include_directories object. Pass that object to `include_directories` argument in whatever you build.

Given your example, I assume that root `meson.build` file is a project build file. Then in that root `meson.build`, for example, you can write:

```
# File: project/meson.build
project('example', 'cpp')
eigen_includes = include_directories('Third-Parties/eigen')
executable('example', 'example.cpp', include_directories: eigen_includes)
```

But if you want to get eigen includes from `src/meson.build`, then you need to change `include_directories` to:

```
# File: project/src/meson.build
eigen_includes = include_directories('../Third-Parties/eigen')
...
```